# xcode 4 Iphone- How to add a compass

Tags: iphone, xcode, digital-compass

How do I make a compass show up in my app? 
There is no compass in the object library that I can just add to my view. So I figured that a compass must be added via code. 
I have been looking at multiple tutorials, but none of them seem to actually have any compass components.
One of the tutorials:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/42992-how-do-i-make-compass.html

I have done everything in it, however nothing shows up. As the same for other tutorials. I had been reading as well saying that I need to enable something in my .plist, but they don't actually say what. Any tips, explanations or tutorials would be amazing!

Comment: Have you tried running your app on a device? I don't think the Simulator is going to be able to tell you anything about which way your phone is pointing.

Comment: yes I have, but with no result :/

Answer (score 3):

It's not really a drag-and-drop component in xcode. You need to:

- Start listening for magnetometer data
- Convert the data from radians to degrees
- Create a view with an image for your compass needle
- Create a timer that every so often tells the compass needle view to animate smoothly to the new magnetometer reading

That's the theory behind it. I couldn't find any simple tutorials when I built mine a few months ago.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about a timer - just set a required accuracy and update the view in the `didUpdateHeading:` method.